# EditText measurements with Drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I wanted to create something like a ComboBox, but the arrow-button on the right-side within the TextView. All the approaches I have seen up till now places the arrow outside the text-field (as an extra button) - which I don't like. To simulate it, I thought I could do it like

```
 android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
 android:ems="10"
```

which looks good, in sense there is on the right side the arrow. I thought I could lay behind it a gradient paint like:

```
 int witdhComboBox = 50;
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    final int bottom = getBottom() - 10;
    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0,bottom,
                                       Color.WHITE,
                                       Color.GRAY,
                                       Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(getRight() - witdhComboBox,
                             getTop() - getPaddingTop() - getTopPaddingOffset()
                                 + getBottomPaddingOffset()
                                 + getPaddingBottom(),
                             getRight() - 8,
                             bottom), paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }
```

but suffer obviously inappropriate paddings resp. incorrect dimensions within the layouts. I looks fine when I'm in the eclipse:

[image]

but when I get on my Galaxy Note it looks too narrow:

[image: too narrow]

and on a HTC Desire it looks too wide (and not properly ending which I wouldn't mind that much):

[image]

Is there a good way to place the gradient directly **under** the arrow? Cause currently I guess its a combined issue of resolution and different style of additional spaces.

Comment: Why don't you add an arrow with background image like you did by paint but not single arrow?

Comment: Well, the idea was to trust on Android reg. the styles. With a custom image, in future version there might be a change. Anyway, your question helped me to rethink the situation and I figured out, it has to do with the density. I have to scale it properly, then it works fine. But I have made the border-settings more or less random, since I have no clue how to retrieve them properly. At least I didn't find a real good values... I would like to retrieve them from Android, and not hand-made ones. But, since it works for the moment ...